# how to use callback in GWT ListGrid.exportdata

Tags: java, gwt, callback, smartgwt

```
btnDownloadExcel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        ApplicationController.isLogout = false;
        final ProgressBarWindow progressBarWindow = newProgressBarWindow();
        DSRequest dsRequestProperties = new DSRequest();
        dsRequestProperties.setExportAs((ExportFormat)
                ExportFormat.OOXML);
        dsRequestProperties.setExportDatesAsFormattedString(true);
        dsRequestProperties.setExportResults(true);
        dsRequestProperties.setExportToClient(true);
        dsRequestProperties.setExportFilename("DownloadLogs.xlsx");
        String title = "Export log";
        String message = "Exporting data...";
        progressBarWindow.setShowMinimizeButton(false);
        progressBarWindow.setIsModal(true);
        progressBarWindow.setShowModalMask(true);
        progressBarWindow.initiate(title, message);
        mainGrid.exportData(dsRequestProperties);
        progressBarWindow.show();
        Timer timer = new Timer() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                progressBarWindow.hide();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(50000);
    }
});
hstack.addMember(btnDownloadExcel);
return hstack;
```

Instead of `Timer`, I want to use callback to hide the progress bar
once export document is done. Timer is not hiding progress bar on time.

Comment: Have you created your RPC service, for which you can make a call?

Comment: Is this GXT? SmartGWT?

Comment: Its SmartGWT. @Thomas Broyer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it like that.
The docs for the callback parameter of exportData says:

> Note that this parameter only applies where DSRequest.exportToClient is explicitly set to false, because file downloads do not provide ordinary SmartClient callbacks

I think that the only way to do it is using a 'server push' mechanism, for example the RealtimeMessaging module of SmartGWT